# Move action center to the left side of screen?

Tags: windows-10, action-center

I'm using a desktop setup with the taskbar on left side. Since I mostly use the track-pad on the laptop, it is rather inconvenient to work with the action center popping up on the right side every time i click the action center icon.
It would be great if the action center would open on the left side of the screen.

Is there any setting or registry tweak for achieving this?
So far no luck with google search.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. This question has been asked several times in the Microsoft support forums going back to 2017 and each time the reply from Microsoft employees is that this is "by design" and that it cannot be moved.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you need to move this window using 3-rd party tool. For example, this AutoHotKey script may help you:

```ahk
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
Run "ms-actioncenter:"
win := WinWaitActive("ahk_class Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow")
mainMonitor := MonitorGetPrimary()
MonitorGetWorkArea mainMonitor, &leftPos, &topPos
WinMove leftPos, topPos, , , win
TrayTip "Moved action center to (" leftPos ", " topPos ")"
Sleep 3000
```

You need to do this only once.

Restart explorer.exe to revert changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've become a full-time Linux user since I posted the question, and I can't imagine going back to Windows now.

Comment: Since I cannot test this anymore, if anyone can confirm this method works, I will mark this answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was setting up a button on Stream Deck using Windows Mover by BarRaider and didn't realize the Action Center had the focus and moved it to the center and left side of my screen (Primary screen 49" wide) and moved it to other monitors too (Secondary screen 27"). Now I'm not sure how to get it back to the right side.

[Desktop Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7arQr.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1158422)